Why is MacBook Air trackpad spanning to completely separate system?
Here's a new one on me....

MacBookAir, M1, OS15.1.1 (Sequoia)
2019 MacPro, Intel, OS15.1.1 (Sequoia)

The two systems are not directly connected, although they are both on the same wifi network, using the same Apple ID, and about 4 feet apart.
Using the trackpad on the MBA, the cursor will span to the monitor on the 2019 MacPro.
Note: not as an "external monitor" on the MBA, but as a direct controller of the MacPro. I can move the MBA's trackpad cursor to the MacPro screen and click, drag, etc on the MacPro, altering the MacPro.
If the MBA's cursor is on the screen of the MacPro, then the MBA's keyboard also alters the MacPro directly.
Anyone know what's going on??
Screen sharing, Remote LogIn, etc. is all off on both systems. File sharing is the only thing enabled on the systems.

This feature is called Universal Control and is part of continuity and what you describe is a non-standard setup (perhaps the OS or pairing is buggy) as the keyboard should follow the mouse to other devices like iOS, iPadOS, macOS.

https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/intro-to-continuity-mchl1d734309/mac

If you disable it, it should go away on any device you don’t want to receive input from another.

turn off “Automatically reconnect to any nearby Mac or iPad.”


Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.
